# How do I remove tinyMCE and then re-add it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am trying to add the tinyMCE editor to my page, remove it, then add it again but am getting errors.

When I run Part A, then Part B, Than Part A again I get the error:

```
Error: g.win.document is null
Source File: tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js Line: 1
```

Part A

```
tinyMCE.init({
    'mode' : 'exact',
    'elements' : '" + ctrl.ID + "Editor',
    'plugins' : 'insertdatetime,TVCMSLink,TVCMSImage',
    'theme' : 'advanced',
    'theme_advanced_layout_manager' : 'SimpleLayout',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1' : 'backcolor, forecolor, |, bold, underline, strikethrough, |, numlist, bullist, charmap, |, undo, redo, |, anchor, link, tvlink, unlink',
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' : '',
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' : ''
});
```

Part B

```
tinyMCE.getInstanceById('" + ctrl.ID + "Editor').remove();
```

Edit:

Below is the full JavaScript function. The first time through it opens the dialog and works, the contents is in the editor and there is no error.  When I click the close button, the dialog is closed. When I run the function again, the dialog displays but the editor is empty and there is the above error.

```
function show_HP1B0() {
$('.EditLink').hide();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'genericHandler.ashx',
    data: 'cmd=select&tableName=ExtraBlocks&id=4',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#HP1B0Editor').html(data['rows'][0]['Content']);
        alert($('#HP1B0Editor').html());
        tinyMCE.init({                 'mode' : 'exact', 
            'elements' : 'HP1B0Editor', 
            'plugins' : 'insertdatetime,Link,Image',
            'theme' : 'advanced',
            'theme_advanced_layout_manager' : 'SimpleLayout',
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' : 'backcolor, forecolor, |, bold, underline, strikethrough, |, numlist, bullist, charmap, |, undo, redo, |, anchor, link, tvlink, unlink',
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' : '',
            'theme_advanced_buttons3' : ''
        });
        var dlg = $('#ctl00_EXTRA_HTML_0_HP1B0Editor').dialog({
            modal: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: 'center',
            zIndex: 99999,  // Above the overlay
            width: 370,
            title: 'Content Block Editor',
            closeText: '',
            open: function () {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                if ($.browser.msie) { $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden'); } $('<div>').attr('id', 'loader').appendTo('body').show();
            },
            close: function () { $('body').css('overflow', 'auto'); if ($.browser.msie) { $('html').css('overflow', 'auto'); } $('#loader').remove(); },
            buttons: {
                'Save': function () {
                    tinyMCE.getInstanceById('HP1B0Editor').remove();
                    $('.EditLink').show();
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
        alert('HP1B0Editor');
                    tinyMCE.getInstanceById('HP1B0Editor').remove();
                    $('.EditLink').show();
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        }).parent();
        dlg.appendTo(jQuery('form:first'));
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('.EditLink').show();
        $('#HP1B0Editor').html('Error');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this editor works but i'd check to make sure when you call `remove` it isn't removing the elements from the page also.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To cleanly remove an editor instance and avoid any errors use:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, editor_id);
```

To reinitialize the instance use:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl',true, editor_id);
```

Be aware that when moving TinyMCE editors in the DOM you need to `removeControl` and `addControl` too, otherwise it results in JS errors.

---

As of **TinyMCE 4** the methods to remove and reinitialize an instance are now...

To cleanly remove an editor instance and avoid any errors use:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, editor_id);
```

To reinitialize the instance use:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, editor_id);
```

Comment: I am getting NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED in firefox, Can you help me on this? Thanks

Comment: @Thariama : I have tried above solution but it's didn't worked for re-initialize tinymce object. But i have fixed myself to adding tinyMce.Editors = [].

Comment: @Rajnish: are you using tinymce3 or tinymce4?

Comment: @Theriama: I've used tinymce4

Comment: can you show your code or maybe create a tinymce fiddle for your issue?

Comment: The TinyMCE 4.x solution worked for me as-is.  I'm using version 4.2.

Comment: @Rajnish see my answer - I was able to get firefox to work by forcing tinyMCE to save before I removed it.

Comment: its not work a lastest version, my opinion add div after textarea, example <div id=edit><textarea></textarea></div> to call re-add $('div#edit').html('<textarea></textarea>') ... basic is work and not try remove!

Comment: As a quick reference for any WP devs here, the main editor id is "content" so it would be `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, 'content');` and `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, 'content');`. This will reset the main TinyMCE on post / page edit.

Comment: tinymce takes the id of the tinymce source dom element and uses that one as the editor id. if the dom elment had no id then 'content' is used

Comment: Do you happen to know where in the tynmce editor lifecycle this fits? It does not cause the oninit event to fire for tinymce editor , making me think that the editor is never destroyed or re initialized. However all the events that I have bound in the on init previously to using removeEditor, no longer fire.

Comment: For those running into the NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED issue with Firefox as mentioned by @Rajnish:  upgrading to the latest (4.4.3 at this time) version fixes it.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my situation. I am loading a tinymce control in a modal dynamically and if the user closed and opened again the control would try to rebind and would break. By removing the editor on close I can rebind on open and everything works. Thanks

Answer (score 41):

Late to the party but it might save someone the headache. Here's what worked for me on version 4.2.4 (2015-08-17):

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];
```

Then I could re-init an editor on the same dynamically created div

```
tinymce.init({selector:"#text"});
```

**Edit : 2020-06-20**

With version: 5.2.x, do

```
 tinymce.activeEditor.destroy();
```

or

```
 tinymce.remove('#myeditor');
```

Comment: This is the best solution that also works when using multiple editors

Comment: @Eric Thanks a lot :D .. I spent the whole day with my tinyMCE inside ASP.Net update panel on Firefox and thought there is no hope. Thanks

Comment: Definitely the best solution. I'd previously used `tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor');` but it wasn't re-initializing.

Comment: Tried this and all other solutions found here. I try to reset the menu/button bars but my custom menus/buttons remains, whatever I do!

Comment: One more to the party - this is what saved me after no other answers in no other threads would.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me as well for version 4.2!

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

```
if (typeof(tinyMCE) != "undefined") {
  if (tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false) {
    tinyMCE.editors=[]; // remove any existing references
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me in Firefox and it doesn't work if you have more than one editor.

Comment: tinymce.init(); not work for me...After add tinyMCE.editors=[]; before .tinymce.init(); works perfectly..thanks..!!

Answer (score 16):

It is now possible to just do

```
tinymce.remove("#id .class or tag");
```

Comment: And you don't need any timeout to call init again.

Comment: And `tinymce.remove()` with no argument removes all editors.

Comment: This is the cleanest one.

Answer (score 9):

In case you have more editors with different settings, this is the way to reastart them preserving settings.

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors.forEach(function(editor) {
    // code injection
    var old_global_settings = tinymce.settings;
    tinymce.settings = editor.settings;
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, editor.id);
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, editor.id);
    tinymce.settings = old_global_settings;
});
```

Comment: This worked great for me, gave me a way to make the editor read only on the fly.  There are plenty of other suggestions out there that say to set the property on the iframe, but this works MUCH better.

Comment: You're saving the old settings, destroying the old editor, making a new one and then assigning the old settings to this editor, but you do this for each editor instance on the page. It's easy as that!

Comment: Gotta deep clone `tinymce.EditorManager.editors` for the for loop as `execCommand` manipulates `tinymce.EditorManager.editors` while the sync loop is going on.

Answer (score 5):

Ok. just a word of caution.

If you have, say.. total of 5 textareas where you want to add/ remove tinymce instances.

**AND**

you want to do this more than once on a given page, Then its better to look for an alternative solution for your requirement.

Why?.. because even though everything would work fine, all the detaching and re-attaching of tinymce is going to take **much** time to execute. The browser will offer to stop the script for you etc.

**source** : my own experience where i tried keeping different textareas in separate hidden divs, and show it to the user when required.

Comment: Did you find alternative js widget?

Comment: i was waiting for this answer. Just testing on 2 textarea script took 300 - 400ms for execution. Tried multiple reinitialize solution still had this huge performance hit.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 tinymce.remove();

    setTimeout(function () {
    tinymce.init(
        {
        selector: 'textarea',
        menubar: false,
        height: "300",
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor ksfm',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bold italic underline strikethrough | link table | ksfm'
        }
        );

    }, 1);
```

Comment: I tried everything: using `mceRemoveControl`, `mceRemoveEditor` and `tinyMCE.get(...).remove()`. Adding a simple timout worked for me! Thanks

Comment: why is the setTimeout needed?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Remove all editors bound to divs
tinymce.remove('div');

// Remove all editors bound to textareas
tinymce.remove('textarea');

// Remove all editors
tinymce.remove();

// Remove specific instance by id
tinymce.remove('#id');
```

[from the tinymce documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#remove)

Comment: `tinymce.remove()
`

actually did the trick for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    var default_value_1 = 'test';
    var default_value_2 = 'test';

    tinyMCE.remove();

    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: '#id_element_1',
        plugins: 'print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help code',
        toolbar: "code formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat"
    }).then(function(editors){
        editors[0].setContent(default_value_1 || '');
    });

    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: '#id_element_2',
        plugins: 'print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help code',
        toolbar: "code formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat"
    }).then(function(editors){
        editors[0].setContent(default_value_2 || '');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

## Just update it !

if you are looking at this to reset the content of the editor, instead of destroying it and initializing it again you can simply change the content like this

```
var editor = tinymce.get('editor_id'); //the id of your textarea
editor.setContent(content);  //any html as string
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove existing tinymce editor and add new needs clearance of tinymce.EditorManager.editors array. This solution works in both cases : 1. If you have only one editor and you want to remove and add it again. 2. If you have multiple editors and you want to remove some special editor and add it again.

```
console.log(tinymce.EditorManager.editors);
```

This will give you a view of the array and exact index of you desired editor which you want to remove. For example one sample output of above console can be:

```
Array[2]
0:B
1:B
length:2
textarea-1:B
textarea-2:B
_proto_Array[0]
```

This is the output of the console when i have two tinymce editors on textareas : #textarea-1 and #textarea-2 Lets suppose I want to delete #textarea-2 and re-add it then it can be done as follows:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors.splice(1, 1);//removing second element in array.
delete tinymce.EditorManager.editors['textarea-2'];//deleting respective textarea id from array
```

Then you can add it again simply using init:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'#ts-textarea-2'
});
```

If you have only one textarea associated with tinymce editor lets say : #textarea-1 and you want to remove and re-initialize it then you can just empty tinymce.EditorManager.editors by :

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];
```

And then you can add using init command as explained above. Worked for me without any error.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions didn't work for me ... This worked fine in my popup close event

```
var editor = tinyMCE.get('txtMailingText');
if (editor!=null) {
    editor.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I ended up doing this:

1. Try to remove the editor right before I add it to the page (this worked for chrome)
2. Before I remove the editor, trigger a save.  This was important for firefox for some reason.

Here is what it looked like to add the editor:

```
  $(function() {
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, 'fred');
    #{tinymce_javascript(:simple_editor, {height: 150, :selector => 'fred'})}
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.tinyMCE-save', function(event) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    return true;
  });
```

I had an explict click that removed the editor:

```
<a href="#" class="tinyMCE-save cool-js-click-handler">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning I used:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, id);
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, id);
```

But those commands run asynchronous, so the add command would often fail. As a workaround, I would:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, id);
setTimeout(function() {
    tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, id);
}, 500);
```

But I hated this solution, because it appeared slower to the user and even so you couldn't be sure that 500 milliseconds was enough if the computer was slow.

Now I'm using:

```
tinymce.remove(id);
tinymce.init({
    selector: id
});
```

I'm not sure why this works, but it works and this code doesn't have any of the asynchronous issues that the old code I used had.

Try it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/g0u059au/