# TinyMCE.init not working on second click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my page there is a list of buttons. Depending on the clicked button the same `.php` file is loaded with a different content for the `<textarea>`. Then TinyMCE is initialised and after that the content of TinyMCE is set.

However, this only works on the first click. When a user clicks a different button, the `<textarea>` is loaded, but TinyMCE is not initialised. I don't know why it's doing that, because it's the same script that is executed.

```
$("ul").on("click", "a.click-menu", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".inject").load("Including/modules/Pages/index.php?page="+id, function () {
        tinymce.init({selector:"textarea"});
    });
});
```

And this is `index.php` in a nutshell:

```
<?php

    echo '<textarea>'.$_GET['page'].'</textarea>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove old TinyMCE and add new one to new controls...

[Heres how it should be made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651676/how-do-i-remove-tinymce-and-then-re-add-it)

Comment: If you are initializing it, you should know it