# TinyMCE doesn't work on second init

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a button, which loads a form when clicked, and another cancel button, which removes the form from dom. When the form is inserted, the textarea is initialized with TinyMCE and it works fine. But after I click cancel, and then load the form for the second time, it doesn't work. I am using TinyMCE 4 and couldn't find a solution anywhere. I am using this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#testarea",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false
});
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$.ajax(
    // ajax call
).done(function(e) {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#testarea",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false
    });
});
```

So, as you can see, I tried reinitializing the plugin after the new content loads with ajax, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either the click event is not unbinding or there is some other issue with your HTML which you haven't provided.

Comment: @EternalHour The only issue is with TinyMCE. THe button works fine, it loads everything as it should do, except that the TinyMCE textarea doesn't get initialized for the second time.

Comment: you should call init once the form loaded, could you please show us the form load code?

Comment: @code-jaff This is the link to the actual demo: http://amarsyla.com/sandbox/profile/ - To reproduce my problem, please click the Edit icon, click Cancel, and then click the Edit button again. That's where the TinyMCE fails to load for the second time.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem I think. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @johnemel No, not yet. I had to postpone my project because of that.

Comment: @AmarSyla I gave up trying and instead of removing the tinymce control from the page and replacing it with a new one, just left it there and re-used it.

Comment: You need to remove the existing tinymce instance before removing the form from the dom.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651676/how-do-i-remove-tinymce-and-then-re-add-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by placing the initialization code at the head section

```
<!-- Place inside the <head> of your HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't help if your field doesn't exist until after an ajax call.