# capturing TinyMCE form textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been unable to get the value of a TinyMCE textarea, I just cant get the value from it?

This is my form (oh so simple):

```
<div id="pow_form_container">
    <form id="pow_content_form">        
        <textarea name="pow_content" id="tiny" style="width:100%">
            <? echo $pow; ?>
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" id="pow" name="pow" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the JQuery ive been using to tray and get the content of the editor

```
    save_pow: function (job_id) {
        var editor = tinymce.get("tiny"),content = editor.getContent();
        $.post('/jobs/save_pow/' + job_id, $('#pow_content_form').serialize(), function (response) {

            alert(content);

            if (response.status == 'ok') {
                tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, "tiny");
                Common_UI.dialog_close('edit_pow_dialog');

            }
        });
    },
```

But what gets posted is :

```
pow_content=++++%09%09++++%09&pow=
```

WTF is that?

I've tried things like:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

SO

```
save_pow: function (job_id) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $.post('/jobs/save_pow/' + job_id, $('#pow_content_form').serialize(), function (response) {

        if (response.status == 'ok') {
            Common_UI.dialog_close('edit_pow_dialog');

        }
    });
},
```

But that doesn't change anything, how can it be this hard? Have a missed something?

I am initializing tinyMCE with this as the text editor is on a jquery UI popup dialog and its the only way I could get the editor to show:
        edit_pow: function (job_id) {
            $.get('/jobs/edit_pow/' + job_id, function (data) {

```
            Common_UI.dialog('edit_pow_dialog', 'Edit Programme of Works', data, {
                'Save': function () {
                    method.jobs.save_pow(job_id);
                }
            });
            tinyMCE.init({ selector:'#tiny' });

        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of the editor with [`getContent()`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent):

```
var editor = tinymce.get("tiny"),
    content = editor.getContent();
```

You should also be aware that you cannot re-init tinyMCE without destroying any previous instances (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4655467/932282)). So before the `dialog_close` you should remove the tinyMCE instance:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, "tiny");
```

Comment: I get the following error when including your code above: TypeError: tinyMCE.activeEditor is null
 

var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

Comment: Is tinyMCE initialized

Comment: Could you add your tinyMCE init statement to the question? What is the value of the `tinyMCE.editors` property?

Comment: Your code seems legit. You should check the properties of the tinymce object, before the `method.jobs.save_pow()` function is called.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help on this. I've implemented your suggestions above and also edited the questions with the updated code. I am still getting errors though:  TypeError: editor is null
 

var editor = tinymce.get("tiny"),content = editor.getContent();

Comment: How do I check properties?